# Open port 8009/tcp on Fortigate necessary?

Tags: security, firewall, port, fortinet

A nmap scan of a Fortigate Firewall showed that TCP port 8009 open is. According to knowledge base articles this is only to download the client for ssl vpn. Is this port used for anything else, and if not - how can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://kb.fortinet.com/kb/viewContent.do?externalId=10773) article:

> FortiClient download portal
>   This feature is available on FortiGate-1000A, FortiGate-3600A, and FortiGate-5005FA2 only.  TCP 8009

I'd imagine this is a needed feature. If you're running scans from your internal network, this port being open is safe. Don't need it? Don't use the FortiClient.

Comment: It was open externally. I don't use the client, so why would it need to be open?

Comment: Good point...according to the KB, it's supposed to be invisible externally in the "default" configuration. I don't have a fortigate firewall to play with, but I'd imagine you can block the port with a rule.